# Symfony and Assetic - where do the defaults point to?

Tags: symfony, assetic

I haven't used Symfony since around 2.6, so I'm trying to relearn the ropes with 3.3.  According to the [default configuration](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/assetic.html) the Assetic `read_from:` and `write_to:` parameters have the values `%assetic.read_from%` and `%kernel.project_dir/web%` respectively.  Where do these actually point to?  I'm guessing that the latter is `/path/to/project/web`, but what of the former?

Also, back in the 2.6 era, I had to register the bundles that Assetic should hook into with the `bundles:` parameter.  Is that no longer needed?  The Symfony docs don't mention it, but the entry is still there (and blank) in the default configuration.

Comment: If you start a new application you should take a look http://symfony.com/doc/current/frontend.html because assetic will be deprecated and not maintained any-more.

Comment: Nice, I had no idea that this was a thing